# Linked List pop_back() function issues

Tags: c++, linked-list

#### List.H

```
void List::pop_back()
{
    if (size == 0)
        cout << "The list is empty and there is no node to pop off the back    of the list" << endl;
    else if (size == 1)
    {
        delete tail;
        head = tail = iterator = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        NodeRef temp = tail;
        while (iterator->next != NULL)
            iterator = iterator->next;
        tail = iterator;
        delete temp;
        size--;
    }

}
void List::begin() //Set the iterator to the head of the list
{
    iterator = head;
}

void List::push_front(int data)             //Inserting a new node in the front of the list
{
    if (size == 0)                          //If there is no nodes in the list, execute the if statement
    {
        head = new Node(data);              //create a new node, and have head point to it
        tail = head;                        //have tail point to the new node also.

    }
    else                                    //If there are nodes in the list, execute the else statement
    {
        NodeRef newNode = new Node(data);   //create a new node
        newNode->next = head;               //have the next pointer point to the head of the next node.
        head = newNode;                     //have the head pointer point to the new node inserted at the beginning of the list
    }
    size++;                                 //Increment the size counter
}

void List::print()
{
    iterator = head;                        //Have iterator point to the head
    if (size == 0)
        cout << "There is nothing in the list" << endl;
    else
    {
        while (iterator!= NULL)
        {
            cout << iterator->data << endl;         //Display contents in node
            iterator = iterator->next;              //Move to the next node;
        }
    }
}
```

#### List.cpp

```
int main()
{
    List B;

    B.push_front(5);
    B.push_front(4);
    B.push_front(3);
    B.begin();

    B.pop_back();
    B.print();

    return 0;
}
```

So the issue I am having is that after the pop_back() function is called and I call the print() function. It has the last node popped but there is a junk number at the end of the list. I believe what is going on is that it is displaying the final node Next* which is an address. I know it has something to do with the else portion of the pop_back() and iterator->next causing it to point to an address.

Comment: Perhaps your problem is in the `print` function - could you also show that? Also - your pop back relies on someone calling `begin` immediately before it, that doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: Why do you believe the final node's `next` should point to NULL? I don't see anywhere in your code where you make it point to NULL.

Comment: @immibis Good question. I think what I meant was that its displaying the final node->next which is pointing to an empty address, not NULL

Comment: Why is `iterator` a member variable and not a local variable?

Comment: @BillLynch Just the way my teacher had us write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. The `else` condition of your `pop_back()` function - You iterate through your list to get to the end, and you correctly release the memory of the last node, but you don't make the `next` pointer of the *new* tail point to NULL. The new tail's `next` pointer is still pointing to some random piece of unallocated memory and is actually a bug.
2. You aren't actually moving the tail pointer. Your inner `while()` loop just gets iterator to point to the same tail as before.

Try changing your `else` statement in `pop_back()` to:

```
iterator = head;
while (iterator->next->next != NULL) {
    iterator = iterator->next;
}
tail = iterator;
delete tail->next;
tail->next = NULL;
--size;
```

This code assumes the size of your list is at least 2 (the above `if` statements take care of 0 and 1, so this should be fine for this code sample).

Comment: I had the same problem, but I set the next pointer of my new tail to null and I still get the same issue. [see here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/323478/linked-list-pop-back-implementation-ignores-pointer-to-nullptr). I asked it on programmers.SE before knowing the same question existed here, and wanted to know your input on it.